# Comment traduire « boilerplate » ?

Tags: traduction, vocabulaire, anglais, informatique

En anglais il existe le mot *boilerplate*, qui veut dire ce qui est souvent répété, avec l'implication qu'on peut « emballer » cette chose et l'utiliser plus tard régulièrement.  Le mot est souvent utilisé en programmation.

Existe-t-il une bonne traduction en français ?

Comment: « Emmitoufler » n'est pas idiomatique ici, je ne comprends pas précisément ce que tu as voulu dire, même si le sens général est clair.

Comment: « Garder au chaud » peut-être?

Comment: Je me demande si le plus idiomatique, au moins dans un contexte informatique, pour cet _emmitoufler_ modifié en _emballer_ n'est pas _encapsuler_.

Comment: @Unfrancophone Non, _encapsuler_ veut dire _mettre dans une boîte noire_, c'est-à-dire masquer le fonctionnement interne d'une partie d'un programme ou d'une couche logicielle.

Comment: @Stamm, c'est bien ce qui me semble être le sens désiré ici.

Comment: Why is nobody differentiating between the two meanings?? The question is about  not boilerplate ***text***.

Comment: Dans quel contexte ? Le terme provient des "press syndicates" et couvrait les contenus prêts à l'emploi (ex: les plaques de bandes dessinées, les feuilletons, les horoscopes, des textes passe-partout sans valeur journalistique) distribués aux journaux clients et pouvant être imprimés sans retouche. L'idée générale est prêt à l'emploi, non individualisé (se retrouve dans [boilerplate T&Cs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boilerplate_clause)). A rapprocher des "[influenceurs](http://bloginfluent.fr/influenceur/)" diffusant quasiment sans retouche du "rédactionnel" fourni par des annonceurs.

Answer (score 11):

Personnellement, j'utilise le mot *squelette*. Par exemple :

> Tu n'aurais pas un squelette pour une procédure PL/SQL ?
>
> Où est-ce que j'ai mis le fichier contenant le squelette pour une classe Java  ?
>
> Ci-joint le squelette pour une page HTML.

Comment: Dans un contexte informatique, j'ai entendu **squelette** pour une procédure, **structure** pour une classe et **plan** pour une page.

Comment: Le squelette ce serait en anglais *template* ou *scaffolding*. Boilerplate a une forte connotation rébarbative qui n'existe pas dans "squelette".

Answer (score 7):

J'utiliserais *modèle* dans le contexte de programmation, ou *gabarit* dans le sens general.

Comment: Je verrais bien un collègue me dire _Here is a template which will gives you all the needed boilerplate._ _Modèle_ conviendrait bien pour _template_, mais pas pour _boilerplate_ pour lequel j'ai du mal à trouver une traduction (on utiliserait _boilerplate_ ici, mais on cause franglais plus que français).

Comment: J'suis d'accord. Il n'y a pas de terme qui correspond exactement. Peut-être 'standard de texte'?

Comment: « texte standard » est peut-être la meilleure proposition jusqu'à présent; mais dans le contexte informatique de Jez, le mot « standard » est quasiment uniquement utilisé comme synonyme de « norme », en particulier établie par un organisme plus ou moins officiel (ISO, AFNOR, ANSI, IEEE, IETF, W3C).

Answer (score 7):

Sur [linguee](http://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais?query=boilerplate&source=english)

- *standard* dans la majorité des textes retenus
- *Formule toute faite*
- *Discours générique* (boilerplate speech)

Cela peut aussi se traduire, dans un contexte ou le fait d'entendre toujours les mêmes argumentations implique une réponse de rejet ou  de relance, ou alors, un point de départ pour un développent.

- C'est une *tarte à la crème* ton truc (argument, explication, ..) cela n'apporte rien de plus.
- C'est un *cliché*, cent fois rebattu que nous allons ...

Comment: "Formule toute faite" me plait beaucoup, d'autant plus que l'usage principal que je connais de *boilerplate* c'est pour des truc genre avertissement et avis légaux divers (*disclaimers*), licenses informatiques etc.

Comment: @Circeus - Dans le cas de règlementation : *conventions habituelles*, **usages courants** devraient convenir, sans toutefois avoir force de Loi.

Answer (score 6):

Pas spécialement heureux des propositions, qui me semblent généralement convenir pour un contenant éventuel de *boilerplate* mais pas pour le qualifier le contenu, ce qui me semble être le sens de *boilerplate*, je tente quelque chose.

Plus péjoratif et familier peut-être que *boilerplate* et pas nécessairement d'un usage aussi courant, *blabla*, *verbiage*, *fatras* accompagné éventuellement de *habituel* ou *nécessaire*.

Pour reprendre l'exemple que j'ai donné en commentaire d'une réponse, *here is a template which will gives you all the boilerplate needed to enable this feature* peut assez bien se traduire par *voici un modèle qui te donnera tout le verbiage nécessaire pour activer cette fonctionnalité*.

Comment: *Verbiage* me plaît fortement. Par contre il ne couvre pas l'utilisation de *boilerplate* en tant qu'adjectif. (Et sur la forme: trop d'italiques tue l'italique. Les deux phrases de la fin entre guillemets ce serait ptêt pas du luxe !)

Comment: Je n'ai pas de proposition. Le français ne permet malheureusement pas aussi facilement que l'anglais l'utilisation de n'importe quel nom comme adjectif. Quant aux guillemets, ajoute-les si tu veux: je viens de changer de clavier et je n'arrive pas à avoir une touche _compose_, je crains devoir me retaper des définitions pour XKB :-(

Comment: Il existe deux acceptions complètement différentes.....ici la question ne portait pas sur boilerplate text in a contract....

Comment: @Lambie, not in a contract, but in a programming context (and my guess is that Jez would have commented if we were all that off).

Comment: @un francophone Je sais. Je viens de le dire. Mais pas tous ceux qui répondent font la ***différence***.

Comment: J'aime cette réponse le mieux car elle garde la connotation négative associée à *boilerplate*.

Answer (score 5):

Dans le contexte de la programmation, j'ai toujours compris **boilerplate** comme tout le fatras de code qu'il faut écrire pour que ça marche correctement sans qu'il apporte quoi que ce soit à la fonctionnalité proprement dite, un peu comme des incantations obligatoires qui lient les parties utiles entre elles.

En général, pour désigner cela, je parle de **glu**.

Answer (score 3):

Dans la même veine que *squelette*, j'utilise *base* et *structure de base* si je parle à des anglophobes. Sinon je garde *boilerplate*.

> Regarde comment c'est fait dans le squelette pour HTML5

Si on veut être plus créatif, on pourrait parler de [*salamalec*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/salamalec), au sens de « politesses figées et verbeuses, mais obligatoires ».

Answer (score 2):

Je ne suis pas une experte de programmation, mais [Termium](http://www.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=&index=ent&srchtxt=boilerplate&where=vpen_xstandard=%27boilerplate%27&dom=KBB&comencdomnsubj.x=4&comencdomnsubj.y=9&comencdomnsubj=Lancer) et le GDT donnent « paragraphe passe-partout » dans le domaine informatique, ou bien « texte standard ». Je ne pourrais cependant pas dire si ce terme est véritablement employé dans le domaine ou s'il ne s'agit que d'une traduction théorique.

Comment: C'est proche, mais pas exactement ça. « Passe-partout » signifie quelque chose qu'on peut réutiliser dans beaucoup de circonstances différentes et est plutôt laudatif. *Boilerplate* signifie quelque chose qu'on est obligé de répéter et qui n'a en général pas un grand intérêt, c'est plutôt péjoratif. Par exemple, les salutations en fin de lettre, c'est du boilerplate mais pas passe-partout.

Comment: Oui, en regardant sur [linguee](http://www.linguee.com/english-french/search?query=boilerplate) passe-partout semble être une traduction plus ou moins adéquate pour *boilerplate* lorsqu'il est utilisé comme adjectif.

Comment: @Gilles J'ai demandé a un ami programmeur qui me dit qu'en programmation, *boilerplate* n'est pas nécessairement péjoratif, sauf si, personnellement, vous détestez travailler avec du code boilerplate.

Comment: @Kareen Je suis programmeur, et je maintiens mon avis ci-dessus. *Boilerplate* n'est pas forcément péjoratif, il peut être neutre, mais n'a certainement pas la valeur laudative de « passe-partout ».

Comment: La banque de dépannage de l'OQLF dit: « Segment de texte mis en mémoire, fréquemment utilisé, pouvant être combiné avec d'autres textes pour créer un nouveau document.» Et le traduit par « passe-partout. »

Answer (score 2):

Je programme en Grande Bretagne et **Boilerplate** introduit également un aspect ennuyeux et sans grand intérêt intrinsèque. Je propose donc du **code bateau** ... c'est a dire banal, sans intérêt autre que sa nécessité au fonctionnement du programme. Notez que je ne sais pas si cela s'utilise dans le monde info en France.

Comment: Je pense que le néologisme serait compris mais ça ne me paraît pas relever de l'usage courant.

Answer (score 2):

En tant que développeur, j'appelle ce code "**de la plomberie**".

Il faut en faire, parfois même beaucoup, mais il faut passer par là pour avoir une joli salle de bain.. En particulier si c'est du code legacy on doit mettre les mains dans la merde en réparant ou en remplaçant des vieux tuyaux qui ne sont plus adaptés. Le terme plomberie permet aussi de désigner le fait que c'est du code qui permet de faire le lien entre deux partie "intéressante". Par exemple, la pompe et la lavabo qui sont respectivement des merveilles d’ingénierie et de design, alors que le tuyau...

Answer (score 1):

"Code standard" ou "texte standard".

Answer (score 0):

The company boilerplate has changed to reflect an increase in the number of employees Voici une autre contexte dans lequel le mot boilerplate a été utilisé, on nous demande d'adapter **la formule consacrée** à décrire l'activité principale de la société et fournir d'autres renseignements.

Comment: _Formule consacrée_ peut en effet servir de traduction pour _boilerplate_ dans certains contextes.  Mais j'ai beaucoup de mal à comprendre dans votre réponse ce qui est exemple, traduction de l'exemple ou glose. Je vous suggère de l’éditer pour rendre cela plus clair.

Comment: La question ne portait pas sur cette acception du mot.

Answer (score 0):

**Matrice** a ma faveur car elle a une signification proche en biologie et math/informatique et que le terme fait directement référence à la matrice en imprimerie (boilerplate in printing industry), ce qui est l'idée quand on parle de boilerplate code.
- https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrice_(imprimerie)

> [...] the term arose from the newspaper business. Columns and other pieces
>   that were syndicated were sent out to subscribing newspapers in the
>   form of a mat (i.e. a matrix). Once received, boiling lead was poured
>   into this mat to create the plate used to print the piece, hence the
>   name boilerplate. As the article printed on a boilerplate could not be
>   altered, the term came to be used by attorneys to refer to the
>   portions of a contract which did not change through repeated uses in
>   different applications, and finally to language in general which did
>   not change in any document that was used repeatedly for different
>   occasions
>   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3992199/what-is-boilerplate-code

***Treillis*** ou ***lattice*** pourraient aussi fonctionner mais je crois que l'on perd le sens originel purement anglophone. Dans une culture francophone, ce serait tout de même plus sensé je crois.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boilerplate_code
- https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrice_(biologie)
- https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrice_(math%C3%A9matiques)

Comment: Tu peux éditer tes réponses pour les compléter/modfier, c'est mieux que d'ajouter des compléments en commentaires.

Comment: Comme je viens de créer mon compte, je n'ai pas le droit de mettre plus de 2 liens dans mon commentaire (il me faut 10 points de réputation pour pouvoir le faire). Merci quand même.

Comment: Ok, je viens de passer les 10 points. C'est fait

Answer (score 0):

Si je devais utiliser un mot français j'utiliserai "commun" ou "code commun".

Boilerplate est une métonymie journalistique qui fait référence au partage d'articles entre journaux (pratique dont je n'ai pu trouver de trace en France). Plusieurs journaux au travers des USA se retrouvant avoir le même article en commun. Puis par extension en juridique les clauses communes dans les contrats portent aussi en anglais le terme de "boilerplate". En français pour les contrats on utilise le terme de conditions générales mais le terme de clauses communes pourraient être compris.

Ceci dit une traduction est toujours dépendante de son utilisation par les locuteurs visés et je ne suis pas sur que des programmeurs français comprennent autre chose que le terme usité aujourd'hui de "boiler plate".

Answer (score 0):

Dans le sens du *"off-the-shelf"* je traduirais personnellement *"boilerplate"* par **Pré-emballé**.

Ça donne un peu le sens du manque d'originalité, du côté industriel/répétitif mais cependant utile et pratique.

Je connais le sens du côté logiciel, mais ça pourrait sans doute marcher dans d'autres contextes.

Answer (score 0):

Il n'y a pas de traduction exacte de "boilerplate code". Le plus proche, à mon avis, c'est "code à la con".

Certes, c'est une expression très familière, mais c'est la seule expression couramment utilisée par les programmeurs pour désigner du code qu'il faut écrire mais qui n'a aucun intérêt en soi, et dont on aimerait bien pouvoir se dispenser.

Answer (score 0):

En programmation, c'est **code répétitif**:

Blog d'un programmeur français.

> Il a été dit un jour que tout problème en informatique pouvait
> théoriquement être résolu en ajoutant un niveau d’indirection
> supplémentaire. Quels problèmes rencontre-t-on lorsque l’on écrit du
> code ? Hé bien, par exemple, **le problème du code répétitif (on parle
> en anglais de boilerplate code).** Comment peut-on s’en débarrasser ? Hé
> bien, on pourrait ajouter un nouveau niveau d’indirection et créer un
> programme qui générerait notre programme ; on pourrait écrire du code
> qui générerait tout ce code répétitif. Cette technique est connue,
> elle porte un nom : elle est l’une des facettes de la
> metaprogrammation.

[code répétitif](https://nauths.fr/fr/2014/05/29/cpp-madness.html)
https://nauths.fr/fr/2014/05/29/cpp-madness.html

Ou bien, une explication:

> créer du code directement réutilisable sans modification (boilerplate
> code).

dans *Découvrir Scilab*

[code réutilisable sans modification](https://docplayer.fr/49496770-Un-livre-de-wikilivres.html)

[Veuillez noter: boilerplate est très souvent utilisé dans le language des contrats pour signaler du Texte générique sur un sujet.]

Comment: C'est impossible que cette réponse soit hors propos.

Answer (score 0):

Voici les mots qui me semblent correspondre (avec des exemples de contexte) :

- **code générique** de connexion à une base de donnée [légérement péjoratif, inisite sur l'aspect banal/interchangeable]
- **code classique** pour lancer une requête HTTP [neutre]
- **code standard** d'ouverture d'une connexion TCP.[neutre]
- **code bateau** d'accès aux données métier. [péjoratif]